# SQL Server Agent+Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Доброго времени суток. Нужно при помощи Java производить настройку расписания извлечения данных в SQL Server, настраивать работу jobs, например редактировать уже готовый, писать туда новый запрос, удалять старый. Есть ли библиотеки для работы со jobs в Java? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Можно только посоветовать пользоваться [системными хранимыми процедурами для управления SQL Server Agent](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sql-server-agent-stored-procedures-transact-sql).